# Binomial Approximation with Small Exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

> Find an approximation for the expression $ (1 + x)^n $, where $ 0 < x < C $ and $ n $ is positive but small.
>   $ C $ is arbitrarily large (<< 1000) and $ n $ is arbitrarily small ($ n << 0.01 $). Is there a known expression for such a case?

Any sugestions are welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Would $\exp(n\ln(1+x))\approx 1+n\ln(1+x)+O(n^2)$ help? I do not think you can do better than the exponential power series if $n$ is the only small quantity.

Comment: Thank you @LutzL